# Geometry Nodes - Instancing from Collections

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections

Using 3.0.0 Beta, it looks like *Instance on Points* replaces the *Point InstanceU node, but using this with collections is stumping me.

I'd like random instances from a collection to be used at each point in some geometry. I see how to use *Collection Info and Pick Instance nodes. But the Instance Index confuses me; is there a way to get the size of a collection and use that to randomize selection? I happen to know my collection has 2 instances and I set the Random Value node accordingly, but I'd like a more general way to do this.

Here is a node tree that I created:

[image]

Is there a way to get the size of a collection?

Comment: if you set the max. Random Value to a large number, as far as I can see, it is taken to be `Modulo(Number of Children)` , so a near-as-doesn't-matter  random selection can be made per-point. Is that good enough?

Comment: This is good enough, and you are correct. I went looking into the sources and found where it does use the modulo of the index, and it looks like my idea of the "size" of the collection may be too simplistic. 

It seems, with your suggestion I should make both the min and max random values higher than the size of the collection; if the random number is smaller than the collection size, the higher indices would be unselectable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts) had a good suggestion: exploit the modulo nature of the instance index input. This is my current solution:

[image]

Comment: Great! If that lookup into the code you mentioned is still handy, maybe you could include a link to it? np if it's too much trouble.

Comment: The source file is [node_geo_instance_on_points.cc](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/geometry/nodes/node_geo_instance_on_points.cc), function add_instances_from_component:



const int index = mod_i(original_index, std::max(src_instances_amount, 1));

Answer (score 1):

Size of Collection in Blender 3.2 (maybe older verisons too). It should work on any geometry type with a Point domain.

Use the *Collection Info Node* as above and connect its *Geometry* with a *Domain Size Node*. Then change the option to *Instances* and it should output the number of objects in your collection.

[image: Node tree connection between Collection Info Node and Domain Size Node to get the size of a collection]

From what I've tested it counts metaballs and subcollections too which could be a problem for some. It does not count the objects in the subcollections.